# Black Bar at top of website when using Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I recently updated my website to the latest version of Wordpress (3.1) and noticed a black bar at the top of the page when using Chrome. It's not present in Firefox or Internet Explorer 8, so I'm not sure what the issue is or where to look.

[Screenshot of said issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwN7M.png)

[See it live here.](http://pixelatedmonster.com/)

Comment: Not visible on my machine in Chrome 10.  Which version are you testing against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that'll almost certainly be something to do with the admin bar - and, as such will be only visible if you're logged in.

Log in, then go to your profile and untick the admin bar on the front end and back end.

Then refresh in Chrome. Should be gone, then :)

Comment: Man, I feel like such a dope for not considering that as being the cause. Thanks a ton!